# how Order By Date in desc when using Union query in sqlite android?

Tags: android, sqlite

How to order the date in desc while using union all query.  Now let me explain my problem  i have fetched the data from two table using union all query now i need to order the data in desc which is in date format when i try to execute am getting :1st ORDER BY term does not match any column in the result set

Let me post my code what i have tried so far:

```
 public List<VisitModel> visitLists(int id,String date){
 String visitquery= " Select * from ( Select  "  + VisitModel.Visit_TravelorCallFlag  + " ," + VisitModel.Visit_ID  + " AS " + VisitModel.Visit_ActionTaken  + " ," + VisitModel.Visit_CheckInDate  + " AS " + VisitModel.Visit_Createdat  +  " ," +  VisitModel.Visit_CheckOutDate  +  " AS " + VisitModel.Visit_LastModifiedat + " ," + VisitModel.Visit_EmployeeName  +  " AS " + VisitModel.Lat + " ," + VisitModel.Visit_Createdby   +  " AS " + VisitModel.Long +  "  FROM " + VisitModel.Visit_Table + " WHERE " + VisitModel.Visit_IncidentID + " =" + id  + " and strftime('%Y-%m-%d', " + VisitModel.Visit_CheckInDate  +") = '" + date  +"' "   +   " UNION ALL "  + " SELECT "  + VisitModel.Visit_TravelorCallFlag + " ," + VisitModel.Visit_TravelID  + " AS " + VisitModel.Visit_ActionTaken +  " ," + VisitModel.Visit_CheckInDate + " AS" + VisitModel.Visit_Createdat + " ," + VisitModel.Visit_CheckOutDate + " AS " + VisitModel.Visit_LastModifiedat + " ," + VisitModel.Visit_StartLat  +  " AS " +  VisitModel.Lat +  " ," + VisitModel.Visit_EndLat +  " AS " +VisitModel.Long  +" FROM " + VisitModel.Visit_TravelTable + " WHERE " + VisitModel.Visit_TravelIncidentID + " =" + id + " and strftime('%Y-%m-%d', " + VisitModel.Visit_CheckInDate  +") = '" + date  +"' )" + " order by  date (" + VisitModel.Visit_Createdat  + " ) DESC " ;


        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(visitquery ,null);
        List<VisitModel>lisobj=new ArrayList<>();
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    VisitModel visitobjs= new VisitModel();
                    visitobjs.setStartLat(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(VisitModel.Lat)));
                    visitobjs.setStartLong(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(VisitModel.Long)));
                    /*       String kil=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(VisitModel.Visit_Kilometer));
                    visitobjs.setKilometer(kil);
                    String time=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(VisitModel.Visit_CheckInDate));
                    visitobjs.setCheckInDate(time);
                    String nextdate=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(VisitModel.Visit_CustOffDate));
                    String endlat=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(VisitModel.Visit_CallSlipNo ));
                    visitobjs.setEndLat(endlat);
                    visitobjs.setNextVisitDate(nextdate);
                    String startlat=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(VisitModel.Visit_Distance));
                    visitobjs.setStartLat(startlat);
                    String empname=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(VisitModel.Visit_EndLong));
                    visitobjs.setEmployeeName(empname);*/
                    String checkin=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(VisitModel.Visit_Createdat));
                    String checkout=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(VisitModel.Visit_LastModifiedat));
                    visitobjs.setCheckInDate(checkin);
                    visitobjs.setCheckOutDate(checkout);
                    int flag=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(VisitModel.Visit_TravelorCallFlag));
                    int primarykey=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(VisitModel.Visit_ActionTaken));
                    visitobjs.setID(primarykey);
                    visitobjs.setTravelrVisitFlag(flag);
                    lisobj.add(visitobjs);
                }
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        cursor.setNotificationUri(mcontext.getContentResolver(), VisitDAO_URI);
        return lisobj;
    }
```

Am getting: `1st ORDER BY term does not match any column in the result set

What does it mean can anyone tell me the solution !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
" order by  date (" + VisitModel.Visit_CheckInDate  + " ) DESC "
```

Try

```
" order by  date (" + VisitModel.Visit_Createdat  + " ) DESC "
```

When you are combining multiple queries with UNION, the sorting is done on the entire result set, so you must use same column from the resultset. 
In this case, this means that you must provide your column's alias name.

**Edit Try this:**

```
String visitquery= 
"SELECT * FROM (
 Select  "  + VisitModel.Visit_TravelorCallFlag  + " ," + VisitModel.Visit_ID  + " AS " + VisitModel.Visit_ActionTaken  + " ," + VisitModel.Visit_CheckInDate  + " AS " + VisitModel.Visit_Createdat  +  " ," +  VisitModel.Visit_CheckOutDate  +  " AS " + VisitModel.Visit_LastModifiedat + " ," + VisitModel.Visit_EmployeeName  +  " AS " + VisitModel.Lat + " ," + VisitModel.Visit_Createdby   +  " AS " + VisitModel.Long +  "  FROM " + VisitModel.Visit_Table + " WHERE " + VisitModel.Visit_IncidentID + " =" + id  + " and strftime('%Y-%m-%d', " + VisitModel.Visit_CheckInDate  +") = '" + date  +"' "   +   
" UNION ALL "  + 
" SELECT "  + VisitModel.Visit_TravelorCallFlag + " ," + VisitModel.Visit_TravelID  + " AS " + VisitModel.Visit_ActionTaken +  " ," + VisitModel.Visit_CheckInDate + " AS" + VisitModel.Visit_Createdat + " ," + VisitModel.Visit_CheckOutDate + " AS " + VisitModel.Visit_LastModifiedat + " ," + VisitModel.Visit_StartLat  +  " AS " +  VisitModel.Lat +  " ," + VisitModel.Visit_EndLat +  " AS " +VisitModel.Long  +" FROM " + VisitModel.Visit_TravelTable + " WHERE " + VisitModel.Visit_TravelIncidentID + " =" + id + " and strftime('%Y-%m-%d', " + VisitModel.Visit_CheckInDate  +") = '" + date  +"' " + " 

)order by  3 DESC " ;
```

Comment: Just try with this " order by   VisitModel.Visit_Createdat  DESC ".

Comment: check my updated this time its not crashing but order by is not working

Comment: Ok, Then instead of just DESC, Write Order by 2 DESC

Comment: what does it do

Comment: See edited answer. Replace whole query and check. Order by 2 DESC: The number represents the index of the column within your select list

Comment: it works but another problem result set updating like first am getting sorted value from visit table and then only am getting value from travel table how to combine result based on date

Comment: Try 3 instead of 2 in order by. Your's is a 3rd column.

Comment: Cheers @Nougat Lover

Comment: Glad it helped :-)

Comment: As your name suggest am having one doubt regarding nougat while click the file using mime type crashed in nougat do you know any problem with that

Comment: File file=new File(DocumentPath);
                     String mime = getMimeType(DocumentPath);
                //    Log.d("type",type);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mime);

Comment: In nougat alone its getting crashed

Comment: file:// is not allowed to attach with Intent anymore or it will throw FileUriExposedException which may cause your app crash immediately called.

Comment: You can check this blog: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en

Answer (score 0):

Please use below example, order by done by column number after merging both queries with union

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
   SELECT * FROM  TABLE_1
   UNION 
   SELECT * FROM  TABLE_2 )
 ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: I saw your code , in your oder by clause  you are providing alias, it will not work. Actual column name is VisitModel.Visit_CheckInDate  and its alias name is VisitModel.Visit_Createdat. Even a simple query without union, order by require actual column not alias. Alias is meant for selecting data only  . As updated earlier try to provide column number i.e. order by 3 desc

Comment: it works but another problem result set updating like first am getting sorted value from visit table and then only am getting value from travel table how to combine result based on date